# How to filter specific file with maven resource filtering

Tags: spring, maven, resources, filtering

My spring+maven project has .properties and .xml resource files. I want to set up filtering for .properties only excluding all spring xml configs. This is pretty straightforward thing:

```
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
```

But now I want to apply filter to one concrete xml file, say env-config.xml. So the problem is how to apply filters to all .properties files and only one specific xml file?

Comment: I believe that in the first resource element you meant to write .properties. Right ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to add one more resource element

```
<resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>path/to/file.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Not sure if it works, I don't have maven right now.

Comment: It does work. Be advised that this will make the maven-eclipse-plugin (if you are at all using it), as it does not handle multiple definitions of `<resource/>`-s pointing to the same directory.

Comment: Note that if you want to add files from the root of your project, you need to specify an empty <directory> tag rather than / (It is relative to the location of the POM)